# Laravel 5.7 CSRF Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, testing, csrf

According to Laravel 5.7 Docs

*"The CSRF middleware is automatically disabled when running tests."*

But I have the following Test

```
public function testUserLoginSuccesfully()
{
    $data = ['email' => 'test@user.com' , 'password' => bcrypt('test12345')];
    $csrf = csrf_token();

    $response = $this->withHeaders(['_token' => $csrf])
    ->post('/login',$data);

    $response->assertStatus(302)->assertRedirect('/home');

}
```

In order to work properly I have to disable csrf protection in the VerifyCsrfToken.php:

```
protected $except = [
    //
    '/login','/register'
];
```

If don't modify this property I'm getting a http 419 error. I don't know what I'm missing or how can I disable csrf only for testing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You dont need to include the csrf token in the call `$this->post('/login', $data)`

Comment: please try to replace `$csrf = csrf_token();` with `$csrf = 'foo';` and see if you get the same error

Comment: It doens't matter if I use a crsf token or not (even a valid one). I'm getting a 419 error. Works with the token only if the routes are added to the $except array and according to the docs the CSRF middleware is disabled during testing. I don't want those routes on the $except array.

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` helped me